# New view but still have the same NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, navigationbar

I have a `NavigationBar` with `UISearchBar`. When I press the searchBar do I want a new view appear but still keep my searchbar active (same navBar). Because if I just use `pushViewController` do a new view appear with a new `NavigationBar` and my `UISearchBar` disappears. Here is my code:

The `UISearchBar`:

```
extension HomeController {

func setupNavigationBar() {

    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.minimal
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.gray
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

}

public func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let firstVC = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    let secondVC = UserSearchController(collectionViewLayout: layout)


    self.addChildViewController(secondVC)
    secondVC.view.frame = firstVC.view.bounds;
    self.view.addSubview(secondVC.view)
    secondVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    secondVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: firstVC.view.frame.size.width, y: secondVC.view.frame.origin.y, width: secondVC.view.frame.width, height: secondVC.view.frame.size.height)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33) {
        secondVC.view.frame = firstVC.view.bounds;
    }

}



}

public func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = nil
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false


}


func hideSearchBar() {
    navigationItem.setRightBarButton(searchBarButtonItem, animated: true)
    label.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.navigationItem.titleView = self.label
        self.label.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { finished in

        })
    }

}
```

The new view:

```
import UIKit


class UserSearchController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually navigation bar does not change, it's still the same object. But when the top view controller changes, navigation controller updates the navigation bar content with the new view controller's navigation item information.

So, you can do two things;
1- You can add the search bar directly as a subview of the navigation bar, not via navigation item. So navigation controller does not change anything about the bar. But i personally don't suggest this, because you will need to handle search bar's visibility on your own.

2- Instead of pushing the second view controller, you can add it as a child view controller to the first one and animate it into the screen appropriately. As the top view controller of the navigation controller does not change, navigation bar content stays unchanged.

Code sample for the second option;

```
// Add the second view controller as a child of the first view controller
[firstVC addChildViewController:secondVC];
secondVC.view.frame = firstVC.view.bounds;
[firstVC.view addSubview:secondVC.view];
[secondVC didMoveToParentViewController:firstVC];

// Now you can animate it as if it's pushed to the navigation controller, or anyway else you want
secondVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(firstVC.view.frame.size.width, secondVC.view.frame.origin.y, secondVC.view.frame.size.width, secondVC.view.frame.size.height);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.33 animations:^{
    secondVC.view.frame = firstVC.view.bounds;
}];
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer! But if i choose the second option, how should I do with the code? I have searched around a little bit but still don´t really get it how I should write the code? I am pretty new with Swift.

Comment: I´ve edited my question and added the code. It still not working, I´m now sure how I should write the code?

Comment: While adding the secondVC as a child, you're creating firstVC as a new HomeController and adding the secondVC to that new instance. Instead you should add it to the HomeController instance visible on the screen (or self, to be more specific).

Comment: Solved it now! Updated my code now. Thank you so much!